# Matrix imag view layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout, android-imageview

I am trying to create a simple memory game. My basic layout is from two fragment one with the cards and one with the moves history. But I am unable to dynamically generate the layout as I wanted.

I want the cards to fit the screen all the time (if screen is small, scale the images).

On the other half (or third) of screen should be listview with the history of moves (no images, just some text representation).

**Desired layout**

[image: Desired layout]

**My result**
[image]

**Layout**

The difference between landscape and portrait layout is linear layout orientation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<fragment
    class="Pexeso.Fragments.CardsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/cardsFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp" />
<fragment
    class="Pexeso.Fragments.HistoryFragment"
    android:id="@+id/historyFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Matrix generating (Xamarin - C#)**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using PexesoGame.Models.Pexeso;

namespace Pexeso.Fragments
{
public class CardsFragment : Fragment
{
    public List<Card> Cards => PexesoGame.Game.Pexeso.Instance.Cards;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var rl = new RelativeLayout(Activity)
        {
            LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
        };
        rl.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);

        int index = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                ImageView img = new ImageView(Activity)
                {
                    Id = index
                };

                img.SetImageDrawable(this.Cards[index - 1].Image);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

                rlp.SetMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    //rlp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft, (int)LayoutRules.True);
                }
                else
                {
                    rlp.AddRule(LayoutRules.RightOf, index - 1);
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    //rlp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentTop, (int)LayoutRules.True);
                }
                else
                {
                    rlp.AddRule(LayoutRules.Below, index - 6);
                }

                img.LayoutParameters = rlp;
                img.SetAdjustViewBounds(true);
                img.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterInside);
                rl.AddView(img);

                index++;
            }
        }

        //return view
        return rl;
    }
}
}
```